# Processing 3.0.1: where does a function return exist in memory when that function is called?

Tags: function, processing, local-variables

```java
Table table;
void setup() 
{
  int i = 0;
    table = loadTable("//location of .csv file","header");
    ResValuesStored(i, table);
    printArray(array[115][50]);
}

int[][] ResValuesStored(int i, Table table)  
   {
    int[][] array = new int[312][743];        
    TableRow row = table.getRow(i);
    array[50][55]   =  row.getInt(0);
    array[115][50]  =  row.getInt(1);
    array[160][60]  =  row.getInt(2);
    array[205][100] =  row.getInt(3);
    array[245][160] =  row.getInt(4);
    array[135][130] =  row.getInt(5);
    array[55][190]  =  row.getInt(6);
    array[185][200] =  row.getInt(7);
    array[100][250] =  row.getInt(8);
    array[240][260] =  row.getInt(9); 
    printArray(array[115][50]);
    return array;
  }
```

If I delete the print operation under the 'setup', the correct value is returned from that same print operation that's contained within the function.

But for some reason the array doesn't exist after calling the function, returning an error "array cannot be resolved to variable", meaning that that same print function that worked before doesn't work outside the function.

Is there a reason I can't perform operations on the array after its created from the function? Does it even exist in memory?

Answer (score 0):

The concept you're looking for is called **scope**. You can find more information on scope by googling, through the [Processing reference](https://processing.org/examples/variablescope.html), or in [this tutorial](http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/basicConcepts/scope) that I wrote.

But basically, a value is in memory* (see below) as long as a variable that points to it is **in scope**. A variable is **in scope** as long as you have **a way to get to it**. In other words, a value is in memory* as long as you have a **variable** that points to it.

Your `array` variable is only in scope **inside your `ResValuesStored()` function**. That's why you get that error when you try to use it outside of that function. As soon as the function ends, that `array` variable goes out of scope.

**However**, since you're returning the value of the array, you can still get to it simply by **saving the return value to a variable**. You'd do that like this:

```java
int[][] returnedArray = ResValuesStored(i, table);
printArray(returnedArray[115][50]);
```

Before, you weren't saving the returned value to a variable, which means that it didn't have any in-scope variables pointing to it, which means that it wasn't in memory* anymore.

There are other ways to keep a variable in scope, such as declaring it at the sketch level instead of at the function level. But the answer to your question is: just save the returned value to a variable to keep it in scope.

***Note**: We're saying values aren't "in memory" when no in-scope variables point to them, but it would be more accurate to say that those values are still in memory, but they are now **eligible for garbage collection**. It's up to Java when that is- it might be immediately, or it might be an hour from now. But we have no way to access those variables, so for your purposes, you can think of them as not being in memory anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it now.